# How to ignore depends with annotation listener in testNG

Tags: testng

I would like perform test with testNG, however, there are dependency on my code, such as use of dependsOnMethods or dependsOnGroups. I would like to ignore those dependency. How can I achieve it with annotation listner?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
public class TestClass implements IAnnotationTransformer
{
    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor,
            Method testMethod)
    {
        if (ifIgnoreDependencies()) // method returns true if you want to skip dependencies
        {
          annotation.setDependsOnMethods(null);
          annotation.setDependsOnGroups(null);
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to make sure that testNg knows about your listener

Comment: My intention is to ignore all the dependsency during running, say 

if (annotation.getDependsOnGroups().length != 0 || annotation.getDependsOnMethods().length != 0){
//ignore the dependency all methods or groups here
}

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you mean. Please rephrase "ignore the dependency all methods or groups here"

Comment: Sorry, let me explain more on that.

In testNG, there are options called dependsOnMethods and dependsOnGroups in which one can insert in @Test  
@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "methodToBeDependedOn" })  public void test1() {....}  
In the above example, method called "methodToBeDependedOn"will be executed before method "test1" as there is a dependency relation among them.  

I would like to use the function in listener so that one can choose to ignore the dependency of test1 on them during run time. But not to totally erase dependency declarartion from my code.

Comment: Sorry for my comment formatting, I am not used to the syntax of stackoverflow reply.
Do you understand my question now?

Comment: Actually, I found the smae qeustion in the forum below, but the sample code link was dead and I can't get the idea of the solution comprehensively, hence I post a question here again. [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#%21topic/testng-users/vKXB8TMKcMY)

Comment: The question was unaccepted. Are there any problems with the answer?

Comment: No, i am green hand to stackoverflow, thus I do not have enough reputation to vote it up.